# ctrl-drag Attaching iphone and ipad button to the same IBOutlet

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

i normally create a button in a view and then ctrl-drag it on the controller's .h header to attach it with an IBOutlet. But now i'm working with 2 different .xib layout files (one for ipad and one for iphone) and i've to attach the same button to the same IBOutlet. Is this possible?

Comment: just control-dragging it? because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but remember to change the File Owner's class of the new/second .xib file.